# sort float python list

Tags: python, list, sorting

Here is my code:

```
for line in lines:
   name,price,yield = line.split(',')
   for part in [price,yield]:
       part = float(part)
       company = Company(name,price,yield)

tempList = sorted(companyList, key=lambda company: company.price)
for company in tempList:
    print(company.price)
```

The printed list ranks 49.0 as smaller number than 5.0
Does anybody know what is going wrong?

Comment: What does company class looks like?

Comment: Don't use ``yield`` as a variable. It's a keyword in Python!

Comment: Shouldn't this code produce a SyntaxError?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

> ```
> for part in [price,yield]:
>     part = float(part)
>     company = Company(name,price,yield)
> ```

does not do what you think it does. The numerical values of `price` and `yield` are not assigned back to their respective original names, but literally to the name `part` (so it is actually overwritten in the second iteration).

The line where you create a `Company` is probably also misindented, it should be outside the `for` loop.

The simplest way to fix this is to replace the three lines I quoted by the following single line:

```
company = Company(name, float(price), float(yield))
```

Comment: As suggested by @mkrieger1: the numerical values got lost in running through the parts. Conversion to float is now done inside object initiation. Only objects without empty strings are created by running through the parts.

Answer (score 4):

It is sorting lexicographically since you are sorting `str` instead of `float`. If you convert `company.price` to a `float` it will sort correctly. Though if this is indeed a numeric value, you should probably ensure that `price` is converted to `float` in `Company`'s `__init__` or something like that.

```
tempList = sorted(companyList, key=lambda company: float(company.price))
```

Comment: Thnx: now the converting is done in the Class __init__.